# Count the number of times each members name appears in a table with a condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Consider the following table:

[image]

Im looking for a query that will:

***- Count the number of times each members name appears in the table*** `where tournament= "EPL" AND round ="12"`

For **this EXAMPLE** the query should return:

Andrew = 3 Wins

Joseph = 2 wins

John = 1 win

Martin = 1 Win

I thought about just using a simple count query as in:

```
Select count(winning_member) as nrWins WHERE tournament="EPL" and round="12" and winning_member = '$mem_name'
```

But this will result in me having to loop over ALL users, which is not an option.

Im completely stuck on this problem...Any input will be much appreciated

Comment: Just remove the `and winning_member = '$mem_name'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for comment guess im overthinking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want the exact output you mentioned you could try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(winning_member, ' = ', count(*), ' Wins')  
WHERE tournament="EPL" 
AND round="12" 
GROUP BY winning_member;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, please tell me if I would like to sum the score_difference row to calc the total score dif for each member (to use in an event of a tie) how will I go about doing that? By including a simple sum function to the query...? Please answer and ill accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: That I am afraid my friend is another question

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
SELECT count(*) as nrWins, winning_member WHERE tournament="EPL" and round="12" GROUP BY winning_member;
```